# Use case in Crystal report which is equivalent to SQL Query

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

How can I use a CASE in my Crystal Report query?

```
select 
    StoreID,       
    Sum(case when Year(Time)=2016 then ExtendedCost end) [Cost(2016)],
    Sum(case when Year(Time)=2017 then ExtendedCost end) [Cost(2017)],
    Sum(case when Year(Time)=2016 then ExtendedPrice end) [Sales(2016)],
    Sum(case when Year(Time)=2017 then ExtendedPrice end) [Sales(2017)]
from F_itemDailySalesParent
```

Answer (score 1):

This is 4 different Case statements with only one option. While I would agree doing that in SQL might be your best choice, in Crystal I think I would just use IF statements.

4 formulas

Cost2016 formula

```
if {fieldforyear} = 2016 then {ExtendedCost}
```

Cost2017 formula

```
if {fieldforyear} = 2017 then {ExtendedCost}
```

Sales2016 formula

```
if {fieldforyear} = 2016 then {ExtendedPrice}
```

Sales2017 formula

```
if {fieldforyear} = 2017 then {ExtendedPrice}
```

Comment: @CoSpringGuy I have to perform sum of ExtendedCost if year is 2016

Comment: You should have a group in your report then. You can use the formulas above in a summary for that group...or the report footer